# Bulk Copy from Table Variable

Tags: sql, sqlbulkcopy

Is it possible to use BulkCopy  for copying data from a table variable to Real table (SQL table) where both schema are identical?

Comment: insert into ... select from  ....

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

```
insert into realTable(col1,col2) select t1.col1,t1.col2 from variableTable as t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * into RealTable from yourTableVariable
```

Comment: what about bulkcopy?, i need bulk copy not row insert